# JavaScript Event Listeners not firing for drag and drop

Tags: javascript

I have a page where I am adding a page level dropzone. And to do that, I have added some event listeners as below.

```
var dropZone = document.getElementById('dropZone');
window.addEventListener('dragenter', function (e) {
    console.log("test");
    dropZone.style.visibility = "visible";
});
dropZone.addEventListener('dragenter', function (e) {
    console.log("test2");
    if (true) {
        e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'copy';
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
dropZone.addEventListener('dragover', function (e) {
    if (true) {
        e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'copy';
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
dropZone.addEventListener('dragleave', function (e) {
    dropZone.style.visibility = "hidden";
});
dropZone.addEventListener('drop', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    dropZone.style.visibility = "hidden";

    //Code to handle the selected files
    HandleDroppedFiles(e);
});
```

This code do add the event listeners to the dropzone element.

[image: Dropzone event listeners]

But when I try to drag and drop files, nothing happens. I instead get the "not allowed" icon (like the image below), just like any other page where drag and drop is not allowed.

[image: Not allowed icon]

There are no messages added in the console log, even at the verbose setting. It feels like browser is blocking the drop somehow before the event listeners are even fired. But, honestly, I have no idea what is wrong and where to start debugging.

Comment: Works fine for me!

Comment: maybe it's saying you're not allowed to drop the file here due to some other issue like cross origin/protocol issues

Comment: It is quite possibly because of the cross origin thing. Let me try it in a different browser.

Comment: Tested on a different machine. It works in a different machine. This is weirdly new.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, there was nothing wrong with my code. It was just chrome being weird. I disabled adblocker, restarted chrome. Nothing worked. Checked google drive and it had same issue.

So, finally I restarted the PC to make sure Chrome is restarted properly. And everything is suddenly working again. SMH.