# Drag and Drop in iframe not working in Spring

Tags: javascript, html, spring, eclipse, drag-and-drop

I am trying to implement drag and drop in iframe in Spring (working in Eclipse 2020-03) and iframe just does not seem to accept any possibility of cooperation. I came across this - arguably older - [snippet of working code][1] but the iframe in eclipse is not even able to accept window.onload. Where is the problem?

EDIT: adding my code

```
<script>
    var dragged;

    /* events fired on the draggable target */
    document.addEventListener("drag", function(event) {

    }, false);

    document.addEventListener("dragstart", function(event) {
        dragged = event.target;
    }, false);

    document.addEventListener("dragover", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }, false);

    document.addEventListener("drop", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        if (event.target.className == "dropzone") {
            dragged.parentNode.removeChild(dragged);
            event.target.appendChild(dragged);
        }
    }, false);
</script>
```

html:

```
<div id="draggable" draggable="true"
        ondragstart="event.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain',null)">
        Drag me </div>

<div class="dropzone">Test dropzone</div>

<iframe class="dropzone">Test iframe dropzone</iframe>
```

Comment: The code you posted is from the supposedly working snippet (which isn't working at all for me). Perhaps provide your own faulty code instead?

Comment: Being a newbie I just copied and slightly adjusted the code from [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API)

Comment: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ro9pbjcd/) for the updated code provided

Comment: interesting...this is not working for me (and I checked in firefox, vivaldi and from another computer in chrome)

Comment: Sorry the JSFiddle is only for the code you gave in the update. Still working on making a example that works.

Comment: I probably should have mentioned that when dragging over iframe, the symbol changes to the 'forbidden' icon like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52196824/javascript-event-listeners-not-firing-for-drag-and-drop) - I already disabled my addblock and restarted everything, but it is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the code from this [example (with jQuery)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22217915/13211030), I came up with the following (although very crude) solution:

```html
<div id="draggable" draggable="true"
        ondragstart="event.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain',null)">
        Drag me </div>

<div class="dropzone">Test dropzone</div>

<iframe id="dropframe" srcdoc='<div class="dropzone2">Test iframe dropzone</div>'></iframe>
```

```js
    var dragged;
    //var dragged2;
    var iFrame = document.getElementById("dropframe");
    var iFrameWindow = iFrame.contentWindow;
    
    iFrame.addEventListener("load", function(event) {
        iFrameWindow.document.body.addEventListener('dragstart', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
      });
        iFrameWindow.document.body.addEventListener('dragenter', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        //dragged2 = event.target;
      });
        iFrameWindow.document.body.addEventListener('dragover', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
      });
        iFrameWindow.document.body.addEventListener('drop', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        //console.log(dragged2);
        if (event.target.className == "dropzone2") {
            console.log('drop event');
            dragged.parentNode.removeChild(dragged);
            event.target.appendChild(dragged);
        }
      });
    });

    /* events fired on the draggable target */
    document.addEventListener("drag", function(event) {

    }, false);

    document.addEventListener("dragstart", function(event) {
        dragged = event.target;
    }, false);

    document.addEventListener("dragover", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }, false);

    document.addEventListener("drop", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        if (event.target.className == "dropzone") {
            dragged.parentNode.removeChild(dragged);
            event.target.appendChild(dragged);
        }
    }, false);
```

A [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ro9pbjcd/1/) is provided as well.

This is what I think you wanted. Is it working perfectly? No, for that I would suggest looking at the jQuery solution (which is way more extensive than my little demo).

**Edit:**

Made a new [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5ecz6g4f/) with a increased *height* and *width* on the *div* inside the iframe. This allows to drop anywhere instead of only on the text.

**Edit 2:**

For some reason the condition `if (event.target.className == "dropzone2")` did not work for me in eclipse; when removed, everything works fine

Comment: Hmmm, it displays the text 'Test iframe dropzone' (something my code did not manage) but still refuses to accept the dragged item. I will definitely look at that jQuery. Thank you!

Comment: Did you drop it directly on the text (_Test iframe dropzone_)? If not it doesn't work, because the _body_ has the listener and is only made up out of the text. Also the _iframe_ text source is in the `srcdoc tag`, or for a file the `src tag`.

Comment: omg, it didnt cross my mind...yes,it works perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: The iframe in Eclipse will not even display the 'Test iframe dropzone' text

Comment: Strange. Is it running directly in Eclipse or starting a Tomcat server instance and opening into a browser on your machine (ie: Chrome, Firefox, Edge, Safari)? Also updated the answer with a bigger drop area on the iframe. **Edit:** It might be caused because of my _"wonderful"_ inline code, try making a separate file from the _div_ and load that using the `src=("file")` tag.

Comment: it starts a tomcat server and opens vivaldi or firefox (I checked both of them, no change)

Comment: just used chrome - no change (so I dont think its the browser settings)

Comment: Really, really strange behavior. I just tested the code in a empty .html file and it works fine in both Chrome and Firefox. How do you inject the code in Eclipse (source would be helpful)?

Comment: Would you be so kind and have a look at [this github repo](https://github.com/grwkremilek/iframe) with my original and your codes?

Comment: Move the `<script></script>` code block to the bottom of your `<body>` and it works (below all the _div_, just before the `</body>`). JavaScript should be loaded last in your DOM, so you want it to be on the bottom always. Placement in _<head>_ is not the way anymore.

Comment: It started to behave differently! The iframe area now recognizes dragover (I added a listener to change colour on dragenter and the iframe indeed changes to purple) but it refuses to drop!